# Random Tweets from past 24 hours using Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to extract 100 random tweets from the past 24 hours that contain the hashtag `#100DaysOfCode`. I'm using `tweepy` in Python.

I'm not sure if this is possible. There used to be a `since` parameter you could utilise, but that's no longer available.

```
 auth = tw.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
 auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET)
 api = tw.API(auth)
 r = tw.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q = '#100DaysOfCode').items(100)
```

Is there a simple solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should use the `count=100` argument to ask for 100 results *per request*. `items(100)` is doing small requests (`count=15` per default) until you reach the 100 results.

Then, a solution could be to request 100 tweets, to check the date of each one and to keep only the ones of the past day, then make a new request and continue until you have your 100 tweets of the past day.

But the best solution is probably to use the Twitter API v2.

The `/2/tweets/search/recent` endpoint has a `start_time` parameter ([see here)](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/api-reference/get-tweets-search-recent).

And you can call it with the `search_recent_tweets` method in Tweepy ([see here)](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.search_recent_tweets)

[remember that you have to use `tweepy.Client` and not `tweepy.API` since it's a V2 endpoint]

Comment: Perfect thank you. Didn't know about Twitter API v2. I'll give that a go.